# How to understand the given sentence?

Tags: meaning

> To say the actors were (i)_____ their director is an understatement: a
>   director who is visibly bored by his cast and their performances is
>   hard to (ii)_____.
>
> **Blank(i)**
>   **A** disappointed in
>   **B** accepting of
>   **C** motivated by
>
> **Blank(ii)**
>   **D** lambast
>   **E** displease
>   **F** suffer

The correct answer is given as BF, but I have no clue how I am supposed to understand the complete sentence. Also, it hardly makes sense to me what after ":" is for explaining the first part of the sentence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence implies that it was plain to see that the director was bored by his cast and their performance, and they had a hard time tolerating (suffering) his display of displeasure. They were not exactly “accepting” of his attitude, which is why saying so would be far from/belittle the truth, an [understatement](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/understatement).

If you are at the receiving end of something unpleasant that you tolerate or put up with (willingly or unwillingly), you could be said to be [suffering](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/suffer) it.

Examples: *I suffered fools so gladly*.  (Line from [Drowned world/ Substitute for love – Madonna](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8VObwbShjg))

The **:** you mention is a [colon](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp).

A colon may be used between independent clauses when the second sentence explains, illustrates, paraphrases, or expands on the first sentence.

Example: *He got what he worked for: he really earned that promotion.*

In your example, both the sentences before and after the colon can stand on their own. However, the second sentence elaborates on the first, which makes the placement of the colon legitimate.